# How can I rotate x-axis labels on a column chart in Angular-js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I have created a column chart using Angular-nvd3.js. The problem I'm having is with the data labels of that chart. I want to rotate these labels vertically. This is the sample code of the chart and an editable link as well.

```
angular.module('mainApp.controllers')

    .controller('discreteBarChartCtrl', function($scope){

        $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'discreteBarChart',
                height: 450,
                margin : {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 50,
                    left: 55
                },
                x: function(d){return d.label;},
                y: function(d){return d.value;},
                showValues: true,
                valueFormat: function(d){
                    return d3.format(',.4f')(d);
                },
                duration: 500,
                xAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'X Axis'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
                    axisLabelDistance: -10
                }
            }
        };

        $scope.data = [
            {
                key: "Cumulative Return",
                values: [
                    {
                        "label" : "A" ,
                        "value" : -29.765957771107
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "B" ,
                        "value" : 0
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "C" ,
                        "value" : 32.807804682612
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "D" ,
                        "value" : 196.45946739256
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "E" ,
                        "value" : 0.19434030906893
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "F" ,
                        "value" : -98.079782601442
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "G" ,
                        "value" : -13.925743130903
                    } ,
                    {
                        "label" : "H" ,
                        "value" : -5.1387322875705
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6t5bky?p=preview

I want the labels to be the same as in the following graph in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rotateLabels` attribute and set the degree,

**Code:**

```
 xAxis: {
  axisLabel: 'X Axis',
  rotateLabels: 90
 }
```

Here is the working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/FN2gnN?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much You made my day

Comment: @TharinduSenanayake did you check the answer for your previous question?

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks for that too :)

Comment: Plunkr link redirects to homepage now.